# Assign a class to a Div based on the last character of a variable?

Tags: angularjs

My code looks like this:

```
<div id="message-area">
   <div ng-cloak>{{ message.text }}</div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me how I can give the inside `div` a class of error if the `app.state.text` ends in a `!`

Ideally I am hoping for a solution where it's all self-contained inside the HTML and not having to have a function I call in the $scope if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-class and call a function on your controller that does the check:

```
$scope.getClass = function(text) {
  return text.slice(-1) === '!' ? 'error':''; 
}
```

### Fiddle

Update:

```
<div ng-class="(message.text.slice(-1) === '!' ? 'error':'')">{{message.text}}</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dieter. Would it be possible for me to just do this inside the HTML only without having another class. I wanted to keep the assignment code near to the DIV if possible. Thanks